# JAjax post with ASP.net webform

Tags: asp.net, post, webforms

i have a page name "TESTAPI.aspx" with purpose is send data to server and get response

"TESTAPI.aspx" with code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {$("#button3").click(function () {
                var x = document.getElementById("demo6");
                
                $.post("TESTAPI.aspx",
                    {
                        name: "Donald Duck",
                        city: "Duckburg"
                    },
                    function (data, status) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
                
            });
});
    </script>
```

"TESTAPI.CS" code:

```
Response.Write(Request.Form.Get("name"));
```

But what i get is the hmlt content of TESTAPI.aspx:
[alert popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTBkN.jpg)
Please help.

Comment: You need to use Web Method in the Web Form to send and receive response data.
See example in the below link.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

Comment: i tried but got notthing like example